# how to compare string using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this function and I want to ensure the params passed in is not duplicated.
For unknown reason, this function is running twice.So I have to find the duplicated params and ignore it, else add it to the href.

Example I have `<a href="xyz.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=151&bfilter=2-Brand[18 And East]">ABC</a>` when the function ran first time.
After that, when it run 2nd time, inside the function, it will compare params which is (`bfilter=[OPQ]`). 
If the OPA already exist, then ignore it, else proceed to add to href.

How can I do that ?

```
function addFilteredAttrURL(params){
    $('.cmpro-accordion a').each(function() {
        var href = this.href;
        if (href.indexOf('?') != -1) {
            href = href + params;
        } else {
            href = href + params;
        }
        $(this).attr('href', href);
    });          
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you fix the `unknown reason` part?

Comment: Your `if ... else` are doing exactly the same thing.

Comment: @cr0ss, yeah i would like to fix the unknown part , but it consume too many of my time....

Comment: Note: The `else` should read `href = href + '?'  + params;`

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the only problem, but your URL generation is invalid as your query string is missing the `?` (if there were no existing query string parameters).

Code should read:

```
function addFilteredAttrURL(params){
    $('.cmpro-accordion a').each(function() {
        var href = this.href;
        if (href.indexOf('?') != -1) {
            href = href + params;
        } else {
            href = href + '?' + params;
        }
        $(this).attr('href', href);
    });          
}
```

if it is run without any existing parameters (first time?) then you will append them without a `?` and it will not be treated as a query string. This might be then causing your parameter check to fail on second time.

Without seeing the rest of the code, it is hard to tell whether it should also have a `&` inserted (when not a '?')

i.e.

```
function addFilteredAttrURL(params){
    $('.cmpro-accordion a').each(function() {
        var href = this.href;
        if (href.indexOf('?') != -1) {
            href = href + '&' + params;
        } else {
            href = href + '?' + params;
        }
        $(this).attr('href', href);
    });          
}
```